# ARSKView not releasing memory on dismissing ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, scenekit, arkit

I am creating an app in which I am using ARSKView. I am seeing that it is not releasing memory on dismissing ViewController. I am not able to find any issue in my code.
Here is my code for using ARSKView.

```
class ARViewController: UIViewController, ARSKViewDelegate {

    weak var sceneView: ARSKView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        sceneView = ARSKView(frame: self.view.frame)
        self.view.addSubview(sceneView!)
        sceneView?.delegate = self

        let scene = CustomScene(size: view.frame.size)
        scene.sceneDelegate = self
        sceneView?.presentScene(scene)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        activateARView()   
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        sceneView?.session.pause()
    }

    var configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    func activateARView() {
        configuration.worldAlignment = .gravityAndHeading
        sceneView?.session.run(configuration)
    }

}
```

Comment: Your scene is holding on to the view controller, and the view controller's view is holding onto the scene.  ARC has no way of getting the VC reference count down to 0 to release

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Can you please specify, where is the problem in the code?

Comment: Already told you

Comment: sceneDelegate is weak.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon apple has solve this issue in iOS 12

Answer (score 0):

The controller is just paused, you can try by setting the controller equal to "nil" just make sure all dependencies are cleared before that.

Comment: once set to nil there is nothing else to do I'm afraid but just wait till the iOS release the memory

If it is in Xcode you're monitoring memory allocation then probably an Ccode issue